# SQL SUM ON JOIN

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, subquery, left-join

sir, I have 3 SQL tables viz stock, purchase, and sold.
in the stock table, I have fields like SKU, qty, MRP, etc
in the purchase table, I have fields like SKU, purch_qty, purch_date etc.
and in the sold table, I have fields like SKU, sold_qty, sold_date etc.

my query is when I want to create a view where I can get to see all SKU with initial qty, sold_qty, puch_qty, availabe_Qty like (SKU, initial_qty, purchased_qty, sold_qty, stock_availabe)

I tried to join these tables on SKU but the result is coming double triple times of quantity.

could you please help me how can I get to this.

my sql query code is

```
    SELECT        stk.id, stk.sku, SUM(stk.qty) AS Initial_Qty, SUM(pur.qty) AS Purch_Qty, SUM(sld.qty) AS Sold_Qty
FROM            dbo.stock AS stk LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.sold AS sld ON stk.sku = sld.sku LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.purchase AS pur ON stk.sku = pur.sku
GROUP BY stk.id, stk.sku
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no image). [mcve].

Comment: BTW, your tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience. I will update the query with relevant tables and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you need to aggregate in subqueries before joining. The logic you want should look like:

```
select st.sku, st.qty stock_qty, pu.purch_qty, so.sold_qty
from stock st
left join (select sku, sum(purch_qty) purch_qty from purchase group by sku) pu 
    on pu.sku = st.sku
left join (select sku, sum(sold_qty) sold_qty from sold group by sku) so
    on so.sku = st.sku
```

Comment: sir is there any way to get available stock as a new coloum